# How to use URL images in SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android

How can I use Universal Image Loader to load images from URLs?
I have HashMap:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,   String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("pict", "http://server/image");
map.put("name", "Name of the picture");
mylist.add(map);
```

Then I have SimpleAdapter:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.prod_listview);
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(prod.this, mylist, R.layout.prod_rows, new String[] {"pict", "name"}, new int[] {R.id.prod_pict, R.id.prod_name});
list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

I gues I should download 'http://server/image',  make it bitmap and in some magical way put it to the SimpleAdapter. But how? 
I saw Universal Image Loader but I do not get it how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to download the images using `Asynctask` process here you have an example of this

[**Loading Image Asynchronously in Android**](http://javatechig.com/android/loading-image-asynchronously-in-android-listview)

Using `ImageDownloaderTask` and setting the image asynchronously in your `ImageView`

```
if (holder.imageView != null) {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
        }
```

Comment: That example is not using SimpleAdapter :(